# x86 weird register call

Tags: windows, x86, ghidra, msvc

I am digging with disassembler inside old game (release year 2002) and something is bugging me, I noticed it has a bunch of... questionable instructions. One of the things it does is calling imported functions indirectly through register, which seems totally unnecessary, example:

```
push someStringPointer
mov esi, dword ptr [->KERNEL32.DLL::OutputDebugStringA] ;pointer inside import table
call esi
```

This could be done without register, since you can just use the absolute address right away. Does using the register serve any purpose? Maybe it's a thing old compilers did? Or some kind of cheap measure against static reversing? I saw it occasionally uses the stored pointer to call something more than once, but it's rare, and doesn't sound like it would improve performance ( more often it wastes up to 3 different registers like that).

I'm using Ghidra to do the reverse engineering and it suggests that this game was compiled with MSVC compiler (it recognised a lot of standard functions from it).

Answer (score 2):

One reason the compiler will do that is if the function is called two or more times in a given block of code. Loading the pointer into a register saves a few bytes of code space and saves a memory deference when compared to just calling into the IAT twice.